# When and Who created linked server?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, linked-server

I came across a linked server that is pointing to production from test environment with **full** access. Is there a way to find out who and when this linked server was created? Based on last modified date, I came to know this was created long back so but with least hope I took a look into default trace - as expected there is no luck.

My test server version is 2008R2.

Comment: It is difficult to trace unless there is some kind of audit is configured.

Comment: You should remove it ASAP. A person with sysadmin rights would have done it.

Comment: Shanky - Thanks for the advise, will remove it soon. Creating a linked server is a pro or con?

Comment: What is Pro or Con ?

Comment: Is "pro or con" a shortening for "good or bad"?

Comment: Yes Andriy. I mean to ask, how carefully we need to handle linked servers or what are the best practices to follow in handling them?

Answer (score 4):

The `sys.servers` data dictionary view will give you the date that the Linked Server entry was modified/created (`modify_date` column), but not who created it.